# Angualr2 : How to do two way data binding for select?

Tags: typescript, angular

I am using angular 2 version **(2.0.0-beta.1)**. I want to create two way data binding for select how should i do?.

```
 <label>Equipment Type</label><br />                
             <select class="form-control">
                <option *ngFor="#equi of EquipTypeDropDown" [value]="equi.key">{{equi.value}}</option>
            </select>
```

And in Component i want its value in ***equiptypeselectedvalue*** variable.

Please guide me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For two-way binding add `[(ngModel)]="equiptypeselectedvalue"`:

```
<label>Equipment Type</label><br />                
         <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="equiptypeselectedvalue">
            <option *ngFor="#equi of EquipTypeDropDown" [value]="equi.key">{{equi.value}}</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: Please provide a Plunker. It depends on how your data looks like.

Comment: Seems you didn't save. The Plunker doesn't contain anything. The `New` button in the Plunker editor provides an Angular 2 TS template.

Comment: do i required specific version of angular2 . Now i am using 2.0.0-beta.1

Comment: `*ngFor="#equi of ..."` needs to be changed to `*ngFor="let equi of ..."` as already mentioned. Otherwise there wasn't any related change since a while.

Comment: <div class="col-md-3">
                <label>Equipment Type</label><br />                
                 <select class="form-control" #t [(ngModel)]="equiptypeselectedvalue" (change)="equiptypeselectedvalue= t.value" >
                    <option *ngFor="#equi of EquipTypeDropDown" [value]="equi.key">{{equi.value}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>                                                                                                                       this code is working for me.. am i doing right?

Comment: Please provide a Plunker. It's too cumbersome to discuss code fragments.

Answer (score -1):

I would have done it this way in v 1.2.x, this may solve your problem:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="value">
    <option ng-repeat="equi in EquipTypeDropDown track by $index" >
            {{equi.value}}</option>
</select>
```

I hope it should work in 2.0.0 too.

Comment: Angular2 syntax is quite different to A1

Comment: But, the concept of `ng-model` must be there. syntax may be different. Use of `ng-model` should solve the problem.